# How to use qemu-system-arm

Tags: qemu

After build an Image (armbian : target board is Allwinner A64), I tried to run this by using QEMU

my commad : qemu-system-arm -cdrom my.img -m 256 -boot d -hda disk.img(created by qemu-img) -machine virt -nographic

But qemu doesn't work

It just shows a Warning message : Image format was not specified for 'disk.img' and probing guessed raw.

Somebody help me

Comment: You can't boot directly from a disk image on the virt board. You need to either pass QEMU a bios image (eg UEFI) as well as the disk image, or else directly pass it a kernel and initrd. You should find a tutorial online for how to boot the kind of guest you want to boot and follow that.